# In my android application how to use the API which is created in dream factory

Tags: android, postgresql, dreamfactory

In Dream Factory I had created a service through which I can get connected to remote postgreSQL and able to do crud operations from there, I had also generated API. Now I have two questions:

1. How will that API get connected to service that I created?
2. How to use the generated API in my android application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try looking at the sample Android app provided by DreamFactory [here](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/android-sdk)

Comment: I had downloaded Dream Factory 2.1.1-2 in my system. I had followed all the steps given in Sample android app docs in github but I am unable to import the sample android app it is showing error as no record(s) detected in request. Please help me out with this?